# How to make observable from multiple event in Rxjs?

Tags: vue.js, rxjs, observable

How are you. I am newbie of Rxjs. I am not sure how to merge observable from different event. I integrated Rxjs with Vue.js

```
export default {
  name: 'useraside',
  data: function () {
    return {
      searchKey: '',
      isPublic: true
    }
  },
  components: {
    User
  },
  subscriptions () {
    return {
      // this is the example in RxJS's readme.
      raps: this.$watchAsObservable('searchKey')
        .pluck('newValue')
        // .filter(text => text.length > 1)
        .debounceTime(500)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(terms => fetchRaps(terms, this.userdata._id, this.isPublic))
        .map(formatResult)
    }
  }
}
```

Now event comes from searchKey changes, now I would like to subscribe same observable when isPublic value change.
So I would like to get raps whenever searchKey changes or isPublic changes.
Thanks.

Comment: just use the merge operator ;) http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-merge

Comment: Thanks. It's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `merge` operator and keep using the `this.isPublic` in your `switchMap`, as Maxime suggested in the comment.

But I'd rather go with a nice a pure dataflow where you listen for the two values and consume them in your handlers. Something like

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
  this.$watchAsObservable('searchKey').pluck('newValue'),
  this.$watchAsObservable('isPublic').pluch('newValue'),
  ([searchKey, isPublic]) => ({ searchKey, isPublic })
)
.dedounceTime(500)
.distinctUntilChanged()
.switchMap(({ searchTerm, isPublic }) => fetchRaps(searchTerm, this.userdata._id, isPublic))
```

Or event better is you can change the initial data structure to something like :

```
data: function () {
    return {
      searchConfig: {
        searchKey: '',
        isPublic: true
      }
    }
  },
```

you can then remove the `combineLatest` and only watch the `searchConfig` property.

The benefit of this implementation is that your dataflow is pure and doesn't depend on any external context (no need for the `this.isPublic`). Every dependency is explicitly declared at the beginning of the dataflow.

If you want to go even further, you can also watch the `userdata` and explicitly pass it down the dataflow :)